# Limit of a function times an improper integral

Tags: real-analysis, limits, improper-integrals

Consider the following expression
$$\lim _{x\to \infty} e^{-\lambda x}\int_0^x e^{\lambda t}f(t)dt$$
where $\lambda>0$ and $f$ is positive, bounded and $\int_0^\infty f(x)dx$ converges. I'd like to characterize this limit, but I'm a little rusty on these things.

First, it should be convergent, because the outer exponent suppresses everything except large values of $t$, where $f$ should be small (for large enough values of $x$).

Moreover, I suspect that the conditions on $f$ are really enough to have that the limit is $0$. If we choose any point $a>0$, then 
$$l_a \equiv \lim _{x\to \infty} e^{-\lambda x}\int_0^a e^{\lambda t}f(t)dt = 0$$
because then the integral is just a number and the exponent then pushes it to zero. We can now consider a sequence of these $l_a$'s where $a \to \infty$, which will of course have the limit $0$. Then, (here is where I make a logical jump) from Heine's definition of limits, it looks reasonable to think the sequence would have the same limit as the original expression.

I've checked this explicitly with a few examples for $f$, i.e. $f(x) = e^{-x}$ and $f(x) = 1/(1+x^2)$, but I'd like to make this proof formal or otherwise find a counterexample.

Comment: Note, incidentally, that $f(x)=1/(1+x)$ doesn't satisfy your assumptions.

Comment: Oops, should've been $x^2$, corrected. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can rewrite your limit to
$$ \lim_{x\to \infty} \int_{0}^{x} e^{\lambda(t-x)} f(t)\,dt $$
The $e^{\lambda(t-x)}$ factor is always less than $1$. And for an arbitrary $N>0$ we can even write
$$ \begin{align} \int_{0}^{x} e^{\lambda(t-x)} f(t)\,dt 
&{}\le e^{-\lambda N}\int_{0}^{x-N} f(t)\,dt + \int_{x-N}^x f(t)\,dt
\\&{}\le e^{-\lambda N} \int_{0}^{\infty} f(t)\,dt + \int_{x-N}^{\infty} f(t)\,dt \end{align}$$
when $x>N$.
The *last* of these integrals goes to $0$ for $x\to\infty$ because you're assuming $\int_0^\infty f(t)\,dt$ to be finite. So the entire limit must be at most $e^{-\lambda N}\int_0^\infty f(t)\,dt$ -- but since $\lambda N$ can be as large as we want, it is actually $0$.

Comment: Wait, doesn't the condition that $N>x$ mean that as you take $x\to \infty$ you must also choose larger and larger $N$'s, such that the last integral doesn't actually get "squished" by the boundaries? Because $x-N$ doesn't diverge.

Comment: @Yoni: Whoops, that was a horrible typo, fixed now. $N$ must be _less than_ $x$, simply to make $x-N$ fall in the domain of $f$.